# Is there a way to tell intelij to ignore a file inside a package

Tags: java

I file inside a package and I want intelij to ignore it. every time I ran my code intelij keeps showing me errors and info from that java file. Is there any way for me to make intelij   to ignore that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may switch-off all error highlighting at the top right corner for this file:

[image: Disable highlighting in IDE]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the file > Override File Type > Plain Text

Note: This action **DOES NOT** override the file type of a specific extension. Instead, it override the file type of a specific file

Comment: is there away to keep the file type as java, and achieve the same result

Comment: No, and why would you like to do so?

Comment: I would like to keep the syntax highlighting.

Comment: As I known, you can't. Why don't just revert the overriding when you need to edit them?